# Page Layouts not available in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

`Page Layouts not available in Sharepoint Designer`. Can it be because I have SP2010 Standard Edition? Or I can make it visible from some settings?

Comment: These type of questions should go http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @skeletank I see what you mean, but this would definitely be too old to migrate http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/189763

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint Designer improved a lot in the 2010 version. The navigation is much easier, as we now have a Site Objects panel:

However, sometimes the Page Layouts link is missing. This is a common scenario:

- You have a subsite in a site collection
- The publishing feature is activated in the subsite, but not in the site collection
- You want to edit/add page layouts on the site collection level, to be used within your subsite
- When you open the site collection in SharePoint Designer, you can't see Page Layouts in the Site Objects panel

You now have 2 options:

1. You can either activate the publishing feature in the site collection (and the Page Layouts link comes back)
2. You can use the All Files link and browse to the master pages and page layouts library (`_catalogs > masterpage`)

Either option will do, unless you really don't want the publishing feature in the site collection. `

Comment: Activated the feature, and Master Pages is still missing in SharePoint Designer. And yes, I am an admin (in the site collection and in the farm), and SPD is enabled in CA. What now?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your site collection, then **Site Actions** -> **Site Settings** -> **Site Collection Administration** ->  and enable "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.

You are **not done** at this point. You should again return to your Site Settings(previous page) and then click on "**Manage Site Features**"
 and activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing**".

Restart your SharePoint Designer and you will find the "**Page Layouts**" in the navigation panel on the left

Answer (score 0):

Check in the needed page layouts from the SharePoint
then reopen the SharePoint designer and you will find them